# discord.js lock a channel for @everyone

Tags: discord.js

When I try to remove SEND_MESSAGES permission from @everyone on a channel, it gives me this error:  `TypeError [INVALID_TYPE]: Supplied overwrites is not an Array or Collection of Permission Overwrites.` And I don't know what to do. This is my code:

```js
let channel = message.channel;
let roles = message.guild.roles;
let testRole = roles.fetch('@everyone');
channel.overwritePermissions(
    testRole, { 'SEND_MESSAGES': false },
    'string'
);

message.channel.send("Successfully locked channel.");
```

Comment: Please do not edit solution announcements into the question. Create yourself an answer instead or accept one of the existing answers.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I got a solution:

```
let role = message.guild.roles.cache.find(r => r.name === "@everyone");
    message.channel.overwritePermissions([{
        id: role.id,
        deny: ["SEND_MESSAGES"]
    }]);
```